# How get specific data from JSON from database column in Spring java

Tags: java, spring

I have some data saved in DB column named **jsondata**
and I want get it into string by stream where I specify which one I want.

for example this stream give me that column which have json data

```java
myRepository.findByID(myID).stream().map(User::getJsonData);
```

```json
{
  "data": {
    "name": "Mike"
    "age": 18
  }
}
```

So I want something like `data.name` and result will be `"Mike"`.

Comment: what about using `ObjectMapper` to map the json to a java class, and use it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use JSON library with query capability such as *Josson*.

https://github.com/octomix/josson

```
Optional<String> json = myRepository.findByID(myID).stream().map(User::getJsonData);
if (json.isPresent()) {
    Josson josson = Josson.fromJsonString(json.get());
    String name = josson.getString("data.name");
    System.out.println(name);
}
```

**Output**

```
Mike
```